# Codeigniter cookie won't set

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

For some reason I cannot set a cookie with an simple example. Every example I found on web failed too. I wonder if I miss something little. Keeps saying "*Cookie not set*"

I added *REFRESH* after setting cookie and another method *get_language()* to read it via link clicking but still no luck.

Thanks in advance

**VIEW**

```
   <p>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/set_language/english'); ?>">English</a>
    <br />
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/set_language/spanish'); ?>">Spanish</a>
    </p>

    <br />
    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/get_language'); ?>">Get Language</a></p>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    var $cookie_name    = 'language';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function set_language()
    {
        if($this->uri->segment(3) != false)
        {
            $cookie = array(
                            'name'      => $this->cookie_name,
                            'value'     => $this->uri->segment(3),
                            'expire'    => '86500',
                            'domain'    => '.language.com',
                            'secure'    => true
                            );

            set_cookie($cookie);

            redirect(null, 'refresh');
        }
    }

    public function get_language()
    {
        if (! get_cookie($this->cookie_name))
        {
            echo 'Cookie not set';
        }
        else
        {
            echo get_cookie($this->cookie_name);
        }   
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to see/use the cookie before reloading the page. That means you need to implement page refresh somewhere after set_cookie($cookie); before you get the state of it.

Another thing, you may wanna change

```
'domain'    => 'language.com'
```

to

```
'domain'    => '.language.com'
```

to make sure your cookie is accessable withing the http://www.language.com, http://language.com and other subdomains.

Comment: I updated code and added refresh after setting cookie but still no luck.

Comment: Do you pre-load cookie helper? - $this->load->helper('cookie'); Also, try passing the path as it is shown in the example here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html (scroll down to $this->input->set_cookie())

Answer (score 0):

First do an easy check ;

If domain is not https and cookie_secure is set TRUE in config.php cookies will not be set. Change to FALSE and it will be set in both http and https.